# Access node based on attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

Within my XML document, each lead or passenger has a `pickup` and `dropoff` attribute, which has a matching `waypoint` id.

```
<r:rides>
    <r:ride>
        <r:lead pickup="1" dropoff="2">
        </r:lead>
        <r:passengers>
            <r:passenger pickup="1" dropoff="3">
            </r:passenger>
        </r:passengers>
        <r:waypoints>
            <r:waypoint id="1">
                <a:place>Hall</a:place>
            </r:waypoint>
            <r:waypoint id="2">
                <a:place>Apartments</a:place>       
            </r:waypoint>
            <r:waypoint id="3">
                <a:place>Train Station</a:place>
            </r:waypoint>
        </r:waypoints>
    </r:ride>
</r:rides>
```

How would I select the `a:place` for each lead or passenger in the XSL? For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="r:lead">
    Route: <pickup goes here/> &#8594; <dropoff goes here/>                                     
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Expected outcome:**

Route: Hall → Apartments

```
<xsl:for-each select="r:passengers/r:passenger">
    Route: <pickup goes here/> &#8594; <dropoff goes here/>                                     
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Expected outcome:**

Route: Hall → Train Station

Comment: Please don't post XML with unbound prefixes. Either remove the prefixes or include the namespace declarations.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you mean something like `xmlns:r="http://www.rideshare.com/ride"`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow cross-references you can define and use a key, define the key with

```
<xsl:key name="by-id" match="r:waypoints/r:waypoint/a:place" use="../@id"/>
```

then you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="r:lead">
    Route: <xsl:value-of select="key('by-id', @pickup)"/> &#8594; <xsl:value-of select="key('by-id', @dropoff)"/>                                     
</xsl:for-each>
```

As the `id`s don't seem to be unique in your complete document more code is needed, in XSLT 2.0 you could use `<xsl:value-of select="key('by-id', @pickup, ancestor::r:ride)"/>`.

With XSLT 1.0 change the key definition to

```
<xsl:key name="by-id" match="r:waypoints/r:waypoint/a:place" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::r:ride), '|', ../@id)"/>
```

and then the key uses to e.g. `key('by-id', concat(generate-id(ancestor::r:ride), '|', @pickup))` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Where would the `xsl:key` value go? Outside the `for-each`?

Comment: The `xsl:key` is a top level element to be put as a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform`.

Comment: Ok I've done this and it works fine for the first `r:ride` node pulled from the xml document, but what I am finding is that on any other additional `r:ride` nodes,  it constantly refers back to the first node (i.e. the one outlined above). Any reason for this? I've created a pastebin of my current document here: http://pastebin.com/6sSFuc63

Comment: Are you using an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor? In XSLT 2.0 it is easy to search only subtrees, with XSLT 1.0 the key needs to incorporate the generated id of the common parent. I will edit my answer to try to outline that change.

Comment: I am using a XLST 1.0 processor